# get data before load entire app as same as splash in mobile apps

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I have a challenge(react-js app) when get data in my web app , is  I have to get some data before loading my pages!!!. I did it with a Modal in "App.js". I have created a modal  and every time that app is loaded ,  the Modal first is shown ,gets data , in next step I navigate it to another route.
I want to say!Is there a better solution? as same as splashes in mobile apps